# RankException when using CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent() on Multi-dimensional Arrays

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I was comparing two Multi-dimensional Arrays for equality like so, when I discovered that `AreEquivalent` throws a `RankException` for any Multi-dimensional Array:

```
object[,] expected = new object[,] { { 
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "", "" } } 
} };
var actual = expected;

CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);   // throws RankException
```

Exception message:

```
System.RankException : The specified arrays must have the same number of dimensions.
```

We can see similar behaviour for a simpler multi-dimensional array:

```
string[,] expected = new string[,] { { "value1", "value2" } };
var actual = expected;

CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);   // throws RankException
```

---

I can get the expected result by using `AreEqual` instead of `AreEquivalent`. Like so:

```
string[,] expected = new string[,] { { "value1", "value2" } };
var actual = expected;

CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);   // does not throw Exception
```

But I don't understand why. Isn't `AreEqual` supposed to be a subset of `AreEquivalent`?

If the only difference between these two methods is that `AreEqual` checks the order and `AreEquivalent` doesn't, then `AreEquivalent` should also evaluate to true.

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding some detail about `CollectionAssert`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems that this is a bug in NUnit. Somewhere in the implementation `ArrayList`'s constructor accepting `ICollection` is used which fails with the aforementioned exception:

```cs
var throws = new ArrayList(actual);
```

Submitted [NUnit bug](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/4252) (and [runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78150) one).

**UPD**

Issue was already fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/4095) and should be available with the next release.